# Does system.Reflection work when I use release folder?

Tags: c#

Does system.Reflection work when I use  release folder ?

Comment: Can you post some code illustrating what isn't working when running via release vs: debug?  There shouldn't be anything inherently different, but like Marc says below, there are lot of factors to consider.  An error, stack trace or other code may help us help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Usually* yes - reflection is just a runtime tool; however, it really depends on what you do with your release that is different to debug; for example:

- do you obfuscate?
- do you merge (ilmerge etc)
- do you sign/strong-name them differently?
- does your release app run with the same privelege / security as in the debugger?
- any caspol differences: running from a network share, for eample?
- is the release framework version / platform the same?
- does your code have any intentional `#IF DEBUG` / `#IF RELEASE` or `[Conditional(...)]` sections?

all of these can impact reflection.

But if *all other variables are the same*, then yes: reflection should be the same between debug and release.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that "Yes, reflection will work regardless of the folder"

Are you running into a particular problem?

Comment: yes, when I start my application in debug folder , anything us good , but when I use release folder , my software not working good.
I also copied any necessary DLL ad files to release folder .